# Ampscript for Dynamic reply mail management

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

I am trying to set a different reply-to email for each country. I found out that I should use the lookup function in this case so I must insert in the “From Email” field in the custom reply email address the following code:

```
 %%=Lookup("ReplyInformation","ReplyEmailAddress","CountryCode", "GB")=%%
```

But I tried to replace the value "GB” by a variable by using the Set function in order to define the countrycode variable (because inserting “GB” is the same like inserting the reply-to email for the clients from GB, so it doesn’t make sense for me), but it didn't work.

```
%%[SET @countrycode = countrycode]%%
%%=Lookup("ReplyInformation","ReplyEmailAddress","CountryCode", countrycode)=%%
```

Furthermore I should use only Data Extension fields in the lookup function, not profile/preference center's attributes. Do you have any suggestions regarding this matter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The recipient is **replying** to an email, so you can't use a context (for example a field in a sendable Data Extension used to send the original email). Remember that original the email has already been sent, and now someone is replying to the email. There are a few AMPscript personalization strings that can be used with RMM:

- _RMM_Headers
- _RMM_ReplyBodyText
- _RMM_ReplyBodyHTML
- _RMM_ReplySubject
- _RMM_JobID
- _RMM_ListID
- _RMM_BatchID
- _RMM_SubscriberID
- _RMM_RecipientEmailAddress
- _RMM_RecipientSubscriberKey

What you seem to want to do is to use the appropriate `countrycode` value based on the Subscriber. You could do this by looking up the country code for a recipient.

Assuming that you have a Data Extension named 'MyDataExtension' and this contains a 'countrycode' and 'SubscriberKey' field, then you can use something like this:

```
%%[
    var @countrycode, @replyemail
    set @countrycode = Lookup("MyDataExtension","countrycode","SubscriberKey", _RMM_RecipientSubscriberKey)
    set @replyemail = Lookup("ReplyInformation","ReplyEmailAddress","CountryCode", @countrycode)=%%
]%%%%=v(@replyemail)=%%
```

You can also use the first Lookup function (instead of `MyDataExtension`) to retrieve a Subscriber profile attribute by using `_Subscribers` as the Data Extension name.

Comment: Hi @Eliot, i configured your code in the Email Address field into the Custom Reply Mail Management, but it didn't work. I probably misunderstood where i should insert the code; do you confirm that is the correct place or i should insert it in the Sender Profile Address as explained [here](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/admin/send_classifications/)?