# Use first name personalization in custom reply mail management

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, triggered-send

I've created a triggered send that sends an e-mail when customers reply to an e-mail. Is it possible to use first name personalization in this e-mail? 
Is the only solution to use the subscriberkey of the session to look up the first name? Because there is no linked data extension for this triggered send.

Comment: Everything you need is here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_triggered_emails.htm&type=5

Comment: This might give you all the info you need on personalization inside an RMM reply: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/157194/ampscript-for-dynamic-reply-mail-management